# Are different offices of same car rental chain (Sixt) in Germany really different?

Tags: germany, car-rentals, munich

I have arranged to rent a car from Sixt in Munich, Germany.
It was two months ago and i don't remember if the car rental near the Central Station (Haubtbahnhof) did not have the car i wanted, if the price was different or if their reviews were bad. As it is i rented from a location at some distance from the station.

However i think we are better of getting a car at the station, as we arrive by train. I have sent Sixt a mail to see if they will change the reservation and how much if anything they will charge.

But I'm curious, is Sixt just Sixt everywhere? Or are those distinct German car rental agencies with their own cars, that just operate under a Sixt umbrella?
Can i expect a big difference in service or price from one location to the next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All offices are operated by the same company and you can expect similar service in all branches.

Prices do however vary a lot depending on the location of the station. Just a check for tomorrow gives me prices between €110 and €170 for a daily rental of the same car depending on where you pick it up. The office at the main railway station is with €145 one of the more expensive locations, simply because customers are willing to pay a premium for picking up the car directly when they arrive by train.

You can change most Sixt reservations, but depending on the tariff you have chosen, you may have to pay an additional fee. In any case, you must pay the difference between the new and the old tariff.

Comment: Indeed, i ended up changing the location to one that is near the S-bahn (I changed from Freimann to Haidhause) and payed about 25 extra. Changing to a location at the central station would have set me back 225 euro! Taking the price from 475 to 700 euro.

Answer (score 4):

They are locations of the same company, but depending on locations, car selection will vary significantly, and prices might vary too:

- It is quite expensive to store a lot of cars downtown, as space is expensive, so if you rent downtown, you probably pay a higher price.
- Similary, renting at an airport often has additional fees included, 20 to 30% extra is not uncommon.
- The best price would be in suburbian / industrial areas, where space is cheap, but it is often hard to get to if you don't already have a car.

Comment: For longer rentals, the cost of a taxi to an otherwise hard to reach area is easily less than the premium of a downtown office, BUT operating hours are also often much more limited in industrial area offices as they're mostly servicing business customers and only open normal office hours.

Comment: I must say that a difference in car selection is surprising, after al they can move cars between locations before the customer arrives. It's not a bakery where the customer chooses upon arrival.

Comment: @Ivana , if you book early enough, sure. If you are a walk-in, selection is often thin. And if you are a premier member, you are allowed to pick from the cars on the lot, and there is not much on the lot for lot size reasons.

Comment: At least in Munich, Sixt seem to consider availability only if you book a car less than 3 hours in advance. With a longer notice, they obviously anticipate to be able to provide any requested car type from a nearby station.